# g_spawn_async_with_pipes () and bash

Tags: bash, glib

I am testing the g_spawn_async_with_pipes () from glib with bash.

I would like to know if it's possible to launch bash with this function as a child process, write commands from the parent to the child (bash) input  and get the result from the bash output?

My c program should act as an interface to an interactive shell.

I think that I don't give bash the good options and that I don't really understand how bash work ( I see in the man page that in interactive mode the bash 's ouptut, input are linked to a tty/terminal).

I have tested a lot of things here is some code:

```
//launcher:
GPid        pid;
gchar      *launch[] = {"/bin/bash","-s",NULL };
gint        in,
            out,
            err;
GIOChannel *out_ch,
           *err_ch;
gboolean    ret;

/* Spawn child process */
ret = g_spawn_async_with_pipes( NULL, launch, NULL,
                                G_SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD | 
                                G_SPAWN_FILE_AND_ARGV_ZERO, NULL,
                                NULL, &pid, &in, &out, &err, NULL );
if( ! ret )
{
    g_error( "SPAWN FAILED" );
    return;
}

/* Create channels that will be used to read data from pipes. */
out_ch = g_io_channel_unix_new( out );
err_ch = g_io_channel_unix_new( err );

/* Add watches to channels */
g_io_add_watch( out_ch, G_IO_IN | G_IO_HUP, (GIOFunc)cb_out_watch, NULL );
g_io_add_watch( err_ch, G_IO_IN | G_IO_HUP, (GIOFunc)cb_err_watch, NULL );

//create channel for input:
GIOChannel * input_channel;
input_channel = g_io_channel_unix_new (in);

//create the string "date\r\n" to send to bash input
GString * cmd = g_string_new("date");
GString * carriage_return = g_string_new("\r\n");
g_string_append(cmd,carriage_return->str);
GError * error;
error = NULL;
gsize bytes_written;
printf("Launching date in bash:\n");
g_io_channel_write_chars( input_channel,
                          cmd->str,
                          cmd->len,
                          &bytes_written,
                          &error);
if (error != NULL)
{
  printf("%s\n", error->message);
}
```

here is the code for cb_out_watch

```
static gboolean
cb_out_watch( GIOChannel   *channel, GIOCondition  cond, gpointer user_data )
{
    printf("->reading bash output\n");
    gchar *string;
    gsize  size;

if( cond == G_IO_HUP )
{
    g_io_channel_unref( channel );
    return( FALSE );
}

g_io_channel_read_line( channel, &string, &size, NULL, NULL );
printf("output : \n:%s\n", string);
g_free( string );

return( TRUE );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `bash` with `-i` and care about *3 IOs*: `fd/0` -> *stdin*, `fd/1` -> *stdout* and `fd/2` -> *stderr*.

... And take a look at `man bash`, searching for *interactive*.

Comment: you mean I should write in /proc/bash_pid/fd0 and add my watchers on /proc/bash_pid/fd1 and proc/bash_pid/fd2

Comment: If your `C` program have to be a *bash wrapper*, you'll have to open and work with 3 file descriptors when forking process to bash (`-i`). Unfortunelly I'm not `C` programmer, so I could'nt write `open` command sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it seems that the /proc/bash_pid/fd/x are only usefull when bash is launched in non interactive mode. As I mentioned before in my question, output/error are redirected to a tty when launched in interactive mode. The only way I can find is to use forkpty and write/read in the new bash. Here is a link for examples I found interesting (even if I just want to write a program that use bash and not some shell mitm ): http://www.scriptjunkie.us/2011/04/shells-terminals-and-sudo-mitm/